# How to add new data items to an existing JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to add new items to an existing JavaScript object as shown below. But both methods throw errors. I could create two separate objects by hard-coding with these values, but want to avoid it.

```
var defaultAmountTypeData = [
  { text: "Dollar", value: "D" },
  { text: "Percent", value: "P" },
  { text: "Sale", value: "S" },
];
var updatedAmountTypeData = [
  { text: "Dollar", value: "D" },
  { text: "Percent", value: "P" },
  { text: "Sale", value: "S" },
  { text: "New Amount", value: "NA" },
  { text: "New Percent", value: "NP" },
];
```

Tried the following:

Solution 1:

```
var updatedAmountTypeData = [
  defaultAmountTypeData,
  { text: "New Amount", value: "NA" },
  { text: "New Percent", value: "NP" },
];
```

Solution 2:

```
var updatedAmountTypeData = getUpdatedAmountTypeData(){
  var newobj = Object.assign(defaultAmountTypeData, {
    text: "New Amount",
    value: "NA",
  });
  newobj = Object.assign(newobj, { text: "New Percent", value: "NP" });
  return newobj;
}
```

Comment: The last code is not a valid javascript

Comment: You dont have a object but array. you could use push. or the spread operator. or concatenate.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski He knows that, the question says he gets errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ellipsis to combine arrays.

```
var updatedAmountTypeData =
    [
        ...defaultAmountTypeData,
        { text: "New Amount", value: "NA" },
        { text: "New Percent", value: "NP" }
    ];
```

Comment: AKA [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).